# Consulta para CDR

Tags: mysql, asterisk

Buenas, estoy haciendo una query para mostrar todas las llamadas perdidas que me llegan en Asterisk en la última hora, pero me encuentro con el siguiente problema:

Si recibo 2 llamadas, una de ellas no respondida y la otra respondida, mi query me muestra la no respondida, me gustaría que solo me mostrara las que verdaderamente no han sido respondidas, en ese intervalo de tiempo.

```
SELECT  
    calldate as FECHA_LLAMADAS,  
    clid as CLIENTE,
    disposition as ESTADO 
FROM 
    cdr 
WHERE
    calldate >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AND 
    disposition="NO ANSWER"
```

Comment: Cuál es la diferencia entre una llamada "no respondida" y una llamada "verdaderamente no respondida"?

Comment: Pues la idea es tener un listado de llamadas, que no han sido devueltas o contestadas, no respondidas son todas las que están en Bd insertadas, y verdaderamente no respondidas son las que ni han sido devueltas las llamadas, o en ese intervalo de tiempo no han sido respondidas

Comment: Cómo se identifica cada llamada entonces?, cómo se puede saber que la llamada que ha sido respondida corresponde con la que no ha sido respondida?

Comment: Con clid  almaceno los números de teléfono, y con  disposition el estado de si ha sido respondida o no, el tema está en que cada llamada es un registro nuevo

Answer (score 1):

Ok, si entiendo correctamente tu pregunta, entonces puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
SELECT  calldate as FECHA_LLAMADAS,  
        clid as CLIENTE,
        disposition as ESTADO 
FROM cdr as c
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT clid 
                 FROM cdr
                 WHERE calldate >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) 
                 AND disposition <> 'NO ANSWER');
```

Comment: ¡Ouch! Dijo el performance. Convendría convertir esto en un `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Por qué piensas que un `LEFT JOIN` tiene mejor performance que `NOT EXISTS`?

Comment: [NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: MySQL](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza sí, justo estaba leyendo ese post y escribiendo un comentario para comerme mis palabras

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tú necesitas en rescatar las llamadas ABANDON,  para Asterisk las llamadas ABANDON son las que no fueron atendidas por algún humano o máquina.

Asterisk inserta toda la información de llamadas de una cola "Queue" (CallCenter) en el archivo /var/log/asterisk/queue_log, por lo tanto deberás buscar ahí la información en donde encontraras el numero del teléfono, tiempo de abandono, fecha y hora, etc. Obviamente no podrás hacer una consulta MySQL para ello deberás volcar ese archivo a una tabla en la base de datos y para hacer eso puedes usar herramientas que provee Asterisk o bien terceros  que se explica en el siguiente link: https://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+queue_log+on+MySQL